# reading properties file from mule server location

Tags: mule

I have configuration file as

```
 <db:oracle-config name="Oracle" host="${db.host}" port="${db.port}" instance="${db.instance}" user="${db.user}" password="${db.password}" doc:name="Oracle"/>
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${hostname}" port="${glport}" doc:name="HTTP" path="url1">
```

Reading all these properties from the mule-app.properties file, which is working fine.

Now the support team in production requires the content of the properties  should be  read from server location and not the mule-app.properties.  The location of the properties is {mule-server-location}/mydir/app.properties.

1) Is it possible to read the properties file from this location?

2) If not, how can I read some content of the file from the conf directory which is located in {mule-server-location}

I have gone the documents [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+Properties), it says to use spring context properties place holder, but when i start the local server filenotfound exception throws. In my studio, where do I keep app.properties file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very simple requirement.
You can use property placeholder to meet your requirement.

A sample XML is shown below.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="file:${mule_home}/conf/myresource.properties"/>
```

You can also specify multiple files using a comma separator.

Comment: ${mule_home} should be declared in mul-app.properties?, how do make to read from context path instead of declaring ${mule_home} in properties file. i.e it should read directly the mule server path ${mule_home} as  mule-3.5.1-app-server/conf//myresource.properties

Comment: You don't need to declare ${mule_home}. This should be implicitly available if you have correctly set up your mule home in environment variables. If not, it should be defined in wrapper.conf file under your mule standalone server. If you have any difficulty using it, you can always use an absolute path.